# Where can I check default actions on browser triggered by keyboard events like keydown 'tab'?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, event-handling, keyboard-events

When I press down 'tab', focused element is changed on browser.
I want to control the order of focused element or skip some elements when tabbing.
I know I can use preventDefault(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to ignore default logic to fire my logic. But I just want to solve it by tweaking default order little bit.

But I can't find any documentation about rules about it.
Where can I check default actions on browser triggered by keyboard events like keydown 'tab'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for either the [tab-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) HTML attribute as demonstrated below (try moving with the tab button), or the [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/tabIndex) JavaScript property.

These are related to which elements can receive the [focus](https://javascript.info/focus-blur#allow-focusing-on-any-element-tabindex); browsers tend to allow this by default for any elements the user is expected to interact with (like button, textarea, etc.)

```html
<label>First</label>
<input type="text" tabindex="1"/>
</br>
<label>Third</label>
<input type="text" tabindex="3"/>
</br>
<label>Fifth</label>
<input type="text" tabindex="5"/>
</br>
<label>Second</label>
<input type="text" tabindex="2"/>
</br>
<label>Fourth</label>
<input type="text" tabindex="4"/>
```